# Will gout finally make patella thinner and thinner if uric acid level has kept being high for long periods?

Tags: urine, gout, uric-acid

My uric acid level has been high and hasn't been able to return back to below normal point for several years.

Since two years ago, my knees have been suffering a lot, which makes me limp. MRI shows that my patella under both knee caps have become very thin.

**Will gout finally make patella thinner and thinner if uric acid level has kept being high for long periods?**